# Setting height DIV jquery dynamic content PHP

Tags: php, jquery, height

I have 2 div.

BODY

```
<div class="div1"></div>
<div class="div2"></div>
```

And I´m trying to assign to put the SAME HEIGHT to both linked to the content (dynamic content from database with PHP)

HEADER

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
var divHeightdiv1= $(".div1").height();
var divHeightdiv2 = $(".div2").height();
if(divHeightdiv1 > divHeightdiv2)
{   
$(".div2").height(divHeightdiv1);   
}
else
{

$(".div1").height(divHeightdiv2);       
}
 });
</script>
```

STYLE

```
.div1, .div2
{
border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Works perfect for DESKTOP computer, but not for mobiles.
Anyone knows WHY?

Note: Excuse any error product of rewriting here the code.
THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

You may want to give it a try with pure CSS (without using jQuery)

The HTML

```
<div class="layout">
    <div class="rows">
        <div class="column div1"></div>
        <div class="column div2"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS

```
.layout {
    display: table;
}

.layout .rows {
    display: table-row;
}

.layout .rows .column {
    display: table-cell;
    border:1px solid #000;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But I´m trying to KNOW WHY it does not work on mobile as work on desktop! :D